# How to update scoped variable across all named views in Angular-UI-Router

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, uiview, angular-ui-router

The following plunker might describe the issue I am facing better:
http://plnkr.co/edit/y7BMdyRhj2WvFXq0UUud?p=preview

I would like to change the value of `resAVal` variable, which is a `$rootScope` variable across all the named views `A`,`B` and `C`. All the named views ARE being managed by the same controller `MainCtrl`.

The `resAVal` could be updated in named view `A`.

I just need the `resAVal` variable updated across all the named views somehow, it doesn't have to be a `$rootScope` variable.

Could somebody help me with it?

Comment: instead of using controller write each of your views as directives, move the variable to a service and inject the service into each directive. Right now your views are highly coupled.

Comment: @Avraam: Is it not possible to have the `resAVal` updated across all the named views in the current system?

Comment: I cant see any clear why to achieve it. I will write an answer explaining.

Comment: @Avraam: Am working with existing system and its a lot of code in the controller and the named views. I need filtering to do based on a checkbox being checked or not. Now the thing is that the checkbox part is shown in a different view than the part that is showing the result of that filter based on the checkbox being checked or not. For filtering, I need the value of checkbox being checked or not. `ng-model` for checkbox being `resAVal`. So, its like I need the `resAVal` value in view `B` in the given plunker while its being updated in view `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working http://plnkr.co/edit/5Ut80w4dhO6IQmSSlx6f?p=preview

I would write it like this:

```
app.directive('aview',['FruitService', function(FruitService){
  return {
     templateUrl: 'a.html',
     restrict: 'C',
     link: function($scope){
       $scope.resAVal = FruitService.resAVal;
     }
  }
}
]);

app.directive('bview',['FruitService', function(FruitService){
  return {
     templateUrl: 'b.html',
     restrict: 'C',
     link: function($scope){
       $scope.resAVal = FruitService.resAVal;
     }
  }
}
]);

app.directive('cview',['FruitService', function(FruitService){
  return {
     templateUrl: 'c.html',
     restrict: 'C',
     link: function($scope){
       $scope.resAVal = FruitService.resAVal;
     }
  }
}
]);

app.factory('FruitService', function(){
  return { resAVal : 5 }
});
```

And actually you dont even have to do `$scope.resAVal = FruitService.resAVal;` in every directive, you can do `$scope.resAVal=yourvalue` in the factory and just inject the factory in each directive

Comment: You've absolutely nailed it! Sheer brilliance. Thanks :)

Comment: @skip Hope it helps ;)